# Setting up MySQL with jetty in a Maven project

Tags: mysql, maven, jetty, jndi, embedded-jetty

I'm new to developing web apps, so for the beginning I've chosen to use Jetty Maven Plugin in order to write my first simple web app. Generating simple Hello world servlet and few test jsps was quite easy but now I'm stuck with setting up connection with my MySQL database. 
I've read a few pages from jetty documentation (both the old one and the new ones at eclipse.org) and with some help of Stack Overflow I managed to create some jetty config files.
Here's my jetty-env.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="lp3" class="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
<New id="lp3" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
   <Arg></Arg>
   <Arg>jdbc/lp3</Arg>
   <Arg>
      <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
         <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename</Set>
         <Set name="User">user</Set>
         <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
      </New>
   </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

But during mvn: jetty:run I'm getting such error:

```
2013-06-28 21:43:24.397:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.3.v20130506
2013-06-28 21:43:24.932:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <New id="lp3" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"><Arg/><Arg>jdbc/lp3</Arg><Arg>|      <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource"><Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename</Set><Set name="User">user</Set><Set name="Password">pass</Set></New>|   </Arg></New> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in file:/C:/Blazej/Java/LP3Voter/LP3Voter/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml
2013-06-28 21:43:24.932:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@a2d6c5{/,file:/C:/Blazej/Java/LP3Voter/LP3Voter/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/C:/Blazej/Java/LP3Voter/LP3Voter/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.TypeUtil.construct(TypeUtil.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configure(EnvConfiguration.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Logger"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.NamingEntry.save(NamingEntry.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.TypeUtil.construct(TypeUtil.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configure(EnvConfiguration.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2013-06-28 21:43:24.962:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1d5ecb6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I've tried to find solution for this. Somewhere I've read that I also have to create another config file - jetty.xml which somehow sets webapp. So I made a jetty.xml which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Call name="setAttribute">
  <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.configuration</Arg>
  <Arg>
      <Array type="java.lang.String">
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
      </Array>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

And after adding it to pom.xml I get another error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.3.v20130506:run (start-jetty) on project LP3Voter: Failure: Unknown configuration type: Call in org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration@19bb90f
```

I also added info about jndi/lp3 into WEB-INF/web.xml file. 
There's also my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.fomfel</groupId>
    <artifactId>LP3Voter</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LP3Voter Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>LP3Voter</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <jettyEnvXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                    <jettyConfig>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm totally confused why it isn't working and after many hours of trying I gave up. 
Can anyone help me finding solution for this? Any idea would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I'm not sure what was the problem but solution for me was to remove *jetty-jndi* and *jetty-util* from pom.xml. After that I had a few exceptions with lack of classes from jetty.jndi so I put it back to my pom.xml. Next I added jetty-util because of missing some log utility and it started to work. Maven is still a mystery to me...